# useEffect to fetch Blizzard API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I am Attempting just to do a fetch on the Blizzard API using useEffect as my hook.  The call goes thru successfully however when I attempt to set my key={item.id} and then try to extract the information I want thru {item.race} I get

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
SyntaxError: /Users/gabrielcastro/Development/code/React/convergence/src/App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (12:2)

  10 |   .then(response => response.races.json())
  11 |   .then(console.log(response.json())
> 12 |   },[races]) 
     |   ^
  13 |  
  14 | 
  15 |   return (
```

This is what my code looks like... I took out the access token just for this post.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function App() {

  const [races, setRaces] = useState('races')
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/playable-race/index?namespace=static-us&locale=en_US&access_token=`)
  .then(response => response.races.json())
  .then(console.log(response.json())
  },[races]) 
 

  return (
    <div>
    {items.map(item => {
   <li key={item.id}>
    Race: {item.name}
  </li>
  })}
     </div> 
     )
    }
```

below is a snip-it of information I am attempting to access
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you returning the list items in your map? I think you should remove the `{}` or add `return`

Comment: Yes I am attempting to return the items, I tried with and without  -- return (
  <div>
  {items.map(item => {
 return <li key={item.id}>
  Race: {item.name}
</li>
})}
   </div> //map over JSON
   )
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.map()` method is only available for arrays. The data you're trying to access might be an object. You need to drill down to the `races` key, which holds the data you need and is in fact an array so you should be able to run `.map()` on it.

Can you try setting the `races` attribute in your state to something like `response.races` to isolate the data you want to work with, then try again.

Comment: I attempted to change the state to  ```const [response.races, setRaces] = useState('races')``` however now its failing to compile

Comment: Inside the first `.then()`, do `console.log(response.json())` and update your question with what what you get (actual code not screenshot). What error did you get when you tried my suggestion?

Comment: You did it in the wrong place. I meant like this:  `.then(response => response.races.json())`

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with the new error I am getting when attempting to use ```.then(response => response.races.json()) ```

Comment: Ok change everything back to how it was when you first made the question and try  `.then(json => setItems(json.races))`

Comment: thank you! working with that change and just adding a return ```return (
  <div>
  {items.map(item => {
 return <li key={item.id}>
  Race: {item.name}
</li>
})}
   </div> //map over JSON
   )
  }```

Answer (score 0):

**Blizard Battle Net API Access Token using Axios React js 100% working**

After update you get access token using this script.
must import Axios in React js.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    Axios({
      auth: {
        // Client ID
        username: "Client ID",
        // Client Secret
        password: "Client Secret",
      },
      method: "post",
      url: "https://oauth.battle.net/token",
      data: formData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
      .then((response) => setToken(response.data.access_token))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

[Console Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYYBP.png)

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's question.